# Is it possible to show two alert views on screen at the same time?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uialertview

When I click a button on an alert view I would like to show another alert view while at the same time keeping the original alert view on screen. At the moment, the original alert view is closed.

Is this possible?

Comment: It really does not sound as a nice UX solution whatever you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vladimir, put it you better don't try working in this direction. This is not certainly going to be good for the users.